# drawing complex stroke (border) in KineticJS

Tags: canvas, border, kineticjs

I have an KineticJS Image.

I want to draw a **border** around this image.

To do that, I am using **stroke**.

```
var x = new Kinetic.Image({
    image: img,
    stroke: 'Red',
    strokeWidth: 5
}
```

- **1-**  Could I have this border with **rounded corners**? Like here [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/rojaboze/1/edit?html,css,output)
- **2-**  Could I give to this border **transparency** that gradually increases from interior to exterior (Let say, from opacity=0.9 to opacity=0.3, with linear decrease)

Can I achieve these with **stroke** or do I need drawing line etc. and create group with the image?

Comment: #2 sounds kind of like shadowing.  Would that be a good substitute in your situation?

Comment: @markE shadow has fixed opacity.

Comment: Fair enough--not a usable substitute in your case :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can draw transparent `Kinetic.Rect` with stroke and rounded corner with your image.

```
    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
       x : image.x(),
       y : image.y(),
       width :image.width(),
       height : image.height(),
       stroke : 'blue',
       storkeWidth : 5,
       cornerRadius : 10
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vadag/1/edit)**

2) There is no easy way to do this. Only if you wil draw stroke manually with `Kinetic.Line` objects.